# I/O Blocking in Green threads

Tags: multithreading, virtual-machine, green-threads

I was reading about green threads and was able to understand that these threads are created by the VM or during runtime and not by the os but I am not able to understand the following statement

> When a green thread executes a blocking system call, not only is that thread blocked, but all of the threads within the process are blocked.

Can anyone please explain how is it possible ?

Comment: It sounds like the wikipedia article is saying that green threads by themselves don't guarantee any sort of concurrency by themselves and that it is up to a scheduler, the green thread runtime or the end user to ensure that calls are performed asynchronously. But really i have no idea :p  The book referenced in the link may provide more context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty simple actually.

"Green Threads" are implemented programmatically inside the VM, which schedules the CPU and memory among them, just like a real OS schedules those resources among OS-level processes and threads.

But from the OS point of view, there is just one thread - the VM itself, so when it makes a blocking system call (on behalf of one of the "Green Threads" it manages internally), this single thread is naturally blocked, and can not do anything, including scheduling the "Green Threads", so the "world stops" for them too.

Comment: Thanks. So can I conclude that a single Erlang process can create thousands of green threads but will be viewed as a single thread by the os hence it blocks ?

Comment: @Mukul Chakravarty

Well, things are a bit more complex with Erlang (as it uses a pretty advanced VM), through the general principle still applies.

A single Erlang VM will use a number of OS-level threads *S* (normally equal to a number of CPUs OS cores available), each acting as a scheduler, capable of running multiple Erlang processes *P* (i.e. "green threads").  It also uses a number of auxiliary "async" threads, for the IO operations.

see http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2010-September/053327.html for a bit more in-depth discussion.

Comment: Thanks that clarifies things.